# errors on mysql says check the manual

Tags: mysql

I've been receiving this error.
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'schoolPass = '300570'' at line 1.
please help here is my code for login.php.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../cn.php';
require_once '../functions.php';

if (isset($_POST['email']) && ($_POST['password'])){
$email = sanitizeString($_POST['email']);
$pass = sanitizeString($_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT schoolEmail,schoolPass FROM schools WHERE schoolEmail = 
'$email' schoolPass = '$pass'";

$result = mysqli_query ($conn, $query) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
$count = mysqli_num_rows ($result);

if ($count == 1) {
    echo "pwede na";

} else {
    $err = "Invalid Log in Credentials";
};

if (isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    echo ("hello.$email.");
};
} else {
echo "email/ password not set";
};
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Note that this code remains open to sql injection. See about prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code line:

```
$query = "SELECT schoolEmail,schoolPass FROM schools WHERE schoolEmail = 
'$email' schoolPass = '$pass'";
```

BY

```
$query = "SELECT schoolEmail,schoolPass FROM schools WHERE schoolEmail = 
'$email' AND schoolPass = '$pass'";
```

Comment: You missed AND operator between email, password condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "
SELECT schoolEmail
     , schoolPass 
  FROM schools 
 WHERE schoolEmail = '$email' 
   AND schoolPass = '$pass'
";
```

In between your two conditions on WHERE, it should be separated by an AND or an OR or a NOT.